# React Native - "Undefined is not an object" error when render a screen that take data from API

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, react-flatlist

I am a newbie on React Native. I am making an application that takes data from API and displays it on the screen. When this screen is rendered gives the following error:
Render Error
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'character.origin.name')

Here codes at screen:

```js
const CharacterDetailScreen = (props) => {

    const { styles, colors } = useThemedValues(getStyles);
    const loc = useLocalization();

    **// state for character detail**
    const [character, setCharacter] = useState([])

    **// this id come from previous screen**
    const { characterId } = props.route.params

    useEffect(()=>{
        Axios.get('character/'+characterId)
            .then(response =>{
                characterDetail = response.data
                setCharacter(characterDetail)
                console.log(characterDetail.name) // if characterId=89, writes "dale" in console
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    },[])
 
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                <Image source={{ uri: character.image }}
                    style={styles.image}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.characterNameContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.characterName}>{character.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.status)}{character.status}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.species)}{character.species}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.gender)}{character.gender}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.type)}{character.type}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.origin)}{character.origin.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.location)}{character.location.name}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default CharacterDetailScreen;
```

I checked the incoming data from API. Is the error due to the fact that the data has not yet come from the api when the page is rendered?

Here incoming data example from API:

```js
const character = {
    "created": "2017-12-01T10:32:08.340Z", 
    "episode": ["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/5"], 
    "gender": "Male", 
    "id": 89, 
    "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/89.jpeg", 
    "location": {"name": "Giant's Town", "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/14"}, 
    "name": "Dale", 
    "origin": {"name": "Giant's Town", "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/14"}, 
    "species": "Mythological Creature", 
    "status": "Dead", 
    "type": "Giant", 
    "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/89"
}
```

Comment: API Url: https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/

Comment: This is because the setCharacter(characterDetail) is async process and it takes time to set the data into the state. The error you are facing is because the "character" state is empty.

Comment: You should load the view when character has some data. Add logic to show view only when data is available in character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to fix this is to pre define your data:

```
const [character, setCharacter] = useState({
    "created": "", 
    "episode": [], 
    "gender": "", 
    "id": 0, 
    "image": undefined, 
    "location": {"name": "", "url": ""}, 
    "name": "", 
    "origin": {"name": "", "url": ""}, 
    "species": "", 
    "status": "", 
    "type": "", 
    "url": ""
})
```

That way you never have to second guess whether a property on character is defined and you dont go through the head ache of adding a null check for each parameter on character you might use.

Another way to address this is to default character to null and render the ui conditionally

```
const CharacterDetailScreen = (props) => {

    const { styles, colors } = useThemedValues(getStyles);
    const loc = useLocalization();

    **// state for character detail**
    const [character, setCharacter] = useState(null])

    **// this id come from previous screen**
    const { characterId } = props.route.params

    useEffect(()=>{
        Axios.get('character/'+characterId)
            .then(response =>{
                characterDetail = response.data
                setCharacter(characterDetail)
                console.log(characterDetail.name) // if characterId=89, writes "dale" in console
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    },[])
 
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {character ? (
                <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: character.image }} style={styles.image}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.characterNameContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.characterName}>{character.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.status)}{character.status}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.species)}{character.species}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.gender)}{character.gender}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.type)}{character.type}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.origin)}{character.origin.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.detailText} >{loc.t(texts.location)}{character.location.name}</Text>
                </View>
            ) : (
                <Loading/>
            )}
        </View>
    );
};

export default CharacterDetailScreen;
```

Comment: Its worked! Thank you so much! Do you any suggestions for solve "source.uri should not be an empty screen" warning?

Comment: Yes use undefined instead of an empty string, or you could pre populate it with a default image